# gnuplot intersection of norm balls

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot the intersection of `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1` and `abs(x) + abs(y) + abs(z) <= 2`

which should be

```
-1<=x<=1, -sqrt(1 - x^2)<y<sqrt(1 - x^2), -sqrt(-x^2 - y^2 + 1 <=z<=sqrt(-x^2 - y^2 + 1)
```

is there a way to plot this with gnuplot ?

Answer (score 0):

my comment to is too long for a comment...
You can plot surfaces in gnuplot, but I don't know how you can plot/visualize them somehow directly in the mathematical form you gave above (I also would be interested if one can.) And I am not aware that you can intersect solid bodies and get the intersection, exclusions, etc. like you get in a CAD system.

Besides this, however, if I plot your bodies the intersect of the sphere (Eq.1) and octahedron (Eq.2) will be the sphere itself, because it is completely inside the octahedron (see image on the left and the center). For example, if you scale your octahedron by 0.75 (image to the right) you will get an intersection which is different from the original sphere.

This is an illustration but still not a solution for what you are looking for.

Some code to illustrate:

```
### start code
reset session
set parametric
set view equal xyz

$Octahedron <<EOD
0 0 2
2 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2

0 0 2
0 2 0
-2 0 0
0 0 2

0 0 2
-2 0 0
0 -2 0
0 0 2

0 0 2
0 -2 0
2 0 0
0 0 2

0 0 -2
2 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2

0 0 -2
0 2 0
-2 0 0
0 0 2

0 0 -2
-2 0 0
0 -2 0
0 0 2

0 0 -2
0 -2 0
2 0 0
0 0 2
EOD

set xrange [-2:2]
set xtics 1
set yrange [-2:2]
set ytics 1
set zrange [-2:2]
set ztics 1
set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
set isosamples 19,13

set multiplot layout 1,3
splot $Octahedron u 1:2:3 w l not, \
    cos(u)*cos(v),cos(u)*sin(v),sin(u) not

set hidden
replot

splot $Octahedron u ($1*0.75):($2*0.75):($3*0.75) w l not, \
    cos(u)*cos(v),cos(u)*sin(v),sin(u) not

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

Illustration:

[image]